# why current work this '_______' even when used_letters updating and what word_letters not removing the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def hangman():
    words = ["aback", "abaft", "abandoned", "abashed", "aberrant", "abhorrent", "abiding", "abject"]
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    print(random_word)

    word_letters = set(random_word)

    used_letters = set()
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)

    while len(word_letters) > 0:
        print("used letters : ", " ".join(used_letters))

        current_word = [letter if letter in used_letters else '_' for letter in random_word]
        print("current word : ", ' '.join(current_word))
        userinput = input("guess a letter : ").upper()
        print(word_letters)
        if userinput in alphabet.difference(used_letters):
            used_letters.add(userinput)
            print(used_letters)

            if userinput in word_letters :
                print("snuk")
                word_letters.remove(userinput)


        elif userinput in used_letters:
            print('u already used this letter ')
        else:
            print('invalid input . try again ')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hangman()
```

why current work this _______ even when used_letters updating and what word_letters not removing the input?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're calling `.upper()` on the user input.  But the word letters are lowercase.  Didn't you notice that the used letters were printed as capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

You are normalizing the user input to capital letters, but the "word_letters" set contains only lowercase letters. You need to use the same case! You could either capitalize the word, or lowercase the user input.

Try:

```
random_word = random.choice(words).upper()
```

Or:

```
userinput = input("guess a letter : ").lower()
```

(Don't try to use both fixes, you only need one or the other.)